# Python. Replacing text between html tags

Tags: python, html, regex, tags, replace

I want to write a function that highlights some text.
It takes a HTML string as input and returns HTML string with additional html tags.

Example:
Input string (need to highlight the word "text"):

```
<div>
<a href="..." title="text to highlight">Some text to highlight</a>
<a href="..." title="text to highlight">Some other text to highlight</a>
</div>
```

Output string:

```
<div>
<a href="..." title="text to highlight">Some <b class="highlight">text</b> to highlight</a>
<a href="..." title="text to highlight">Some other <b class="highlight">text</b> to highlight</a>
</div>
```

I have found a regexp that matches text only between html tags, but I can't figure out how to surround some part of it with additional tags

```
highlight_str = u'text'
p = re.compile(r"[^<>]+(?=[<])")
    iterator = p.finditer(search_str)
    for match in iterator:
        # code for replacement here ???
```

Is there any other ideas to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Seriously, the parade of programmers using regular expressions on HTML is endless.

Comment: That regex doesn't work for anything other than a rigged demo.

Comment: Ok. I've understood. It is wasn't a good idea to do it with regex.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: Could you give a little more info how to make it with Beautiful Soup?